How to find the keyboard layout that matches the physical keyboard
I have got hold of an old (2017) Dell Latitude 5491 that I need to use for a while. It has a very strange keyboard, probably not the original, see the image. In particular the key between the enter and backspace also has the pipe and backslash symbol, though none of the obvious combinations of shift, alt, ctrl etc. output them. Any idea how to map this correctly and actually type the pipe and backslash? Running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, output of setxkbmap -query is
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us



Does the key work under other operating systems? It might be a hardware failure. Using the program xev, is there any output when pressing that key?

The key works, as in pressing it generates a hash symbol and shift+key generates a tilde. It just doesn't output the slash and pipe symbols. In case it's of any interest I tried a number of approaches from xmodmap to manually editing the keyboard configuration files and the biggest roadblock was getting it to work in the terminal (where the pipe is needed most!). Probably there is a way to do it but I couldn't figure it out.
What I did in the end was switch the keyboard layout to US which no longer matches the physical layout, but at least I can type a backslash.
